# Solving System of Differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

The general solution to differential equation
$$x'=Ax$$ where A is a square matrix is given by solving for the eigenvalues and then eigen vectors of matrix $A$. However, is there a general method if I have $$x'=Ax+b$$ where $b$ is a vector of length same a $x$?

The straight method to attack it would be to integrate to obtain:
$$x-A\frac{x^2}{2}-b=0$$
and solve:
$$x^2-2A^{-1}x+2A^{-1}b=0$$
$$x=\frac{2A^{-1}\pm\sqrt{(2A^{-1})^2-8A^{-1}}}{2}$$
Is there any steop ahead of this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there exists a vector $v$ such that $Av=b$ then consider the variable $y=x-v$.  One finds $y'=Ay$.

If there is no such $v$ then $A$ is not invertible. If $A$ is still diagonalizable, however, then the tricky part of $b$ is the bit lying in the kernel of the matrix. Thus write $b=b_0+c$ where $Ab_0=0$ but there is some $Av=c$ solution. Try computing $y=x-v+tb_0$.

That's the easiest cases to deal with.

---

By the way your attempt to integrate is doomed to failure, because these are vectors not numbers, and you've integrated one thing with respect to $t$ andtheother to $x$!

Comment: Thanks. For answer and comment on my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

To solve
$$
x'=Ax+b
$$
use
$$
x=e^{At}x_0-A^{-1}b
$$
where $e^{At}x_0$ is the solution to $x'=Ax$.

Often times it is useful to look at the $1$-dimensional analog:
$$
x'=ax+b
$$
where the solution is
$$
x=x_0e^{at}-b/a
$$
I just put that solution into matrix form and checked it out to make sure it worked. Low tech math.